# Error in extracting data from xml files using python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to extract data from a xml file  and trying to print the object names,But I am getting this error:

```
File "new.py", line 11, in <module>
    dom=ElementTree.parse(image_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 647, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abc.xml'
```

Although the program knows the file name but still is says no file name.Here is my python program:

```
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree
path="/home/sultan/Desktop/xmltxt/xmlfiles"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
savedir='textfiles'
for image_file in (dirs):
    if not os.path.isdir(savedir):
        os.mkdir(savedir)


    dom=ElementTree.parse(image_file)
    labels=dom.findall('object/name')
    for lbl in labels:
       print(lbl)
```

here is the content of my xml file:

```
<annotation>
<folder>images</folder>
<filename>3rdtrk6.jpg</filename>
<segmented>0</segmented>
<size>
<width>1920</width>
<height>1080</height>
<depth>3</depth>
</size>
<object>
<name>truck</name>
<pose>Unspecified</pose>
<truncated>0</truncated>
<difficult>0</difficult>
<bndbox>
<xmin>959</xmin>
<ymin>388</ymin>
<xmax>1411</xmax>
<ymax>889</ymax>
</bndbox>
</object>
<object>
<name>bus</name>
<pose>Unspecified</pose>
<truncated>0</truncated>
<difficult>0</difficult>
<bndbox><xmin>220</xmin>
<ymin>264</ymin>
<xmax>471</xmax>
<ymax>465</ymax>
</bndbox>
</object>
</annotation>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the full path to the file. Use `os.path.join(path, image_file)`

**Ex:**

```
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree
path="/home/sultan/Desktop/xmltxt/xmlfiles"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
savedir='textfiles'
for image_file in (dirs):
    if not os.path.isdir(savedir):
        os.mkdir(savedir)


    dom=ElementTree.parse(os.path.join(path, image_file))
    labels=dom.findall('object/name')
    for lbl in labels:
       print(lbl)
```